# Issue in deploying restlet based application on tomcat

Tags: tomcat, deployment, restlet

I am having issue in deploying restlet application on tomcat webserver.

I am able to run the application directly from eclipse but when I deploy on tomcat I get issues like the following.

```
    May 10, 2015 10:04:32 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader loadClass
    INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load org.simpleframework.transport.connect.Connection.
  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
    java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1566)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Unknown Source)
        at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelper(Engine.java:781)
        at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelpers(Engine.java:813)
        at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelpers(Engine.java:853)
        at org.restlet.engine.Engine.discoverConnectors(Engine.java:544)
        at org.restlet.engine.Engine.<init>(Engine.java:379)
        at org.restlet.engine.Engine.register(Engine.java:301)
        at org.restlet.engine.Engine.register(Engine.java:290)
        at org.restlet.engine.Engine.getInstance(Engine.java:199)
        at org.restlet.data.Method.<init>(Method.java:337)
        at org.restlet.data.Method.<init>(Method.java:396)
        at org.restlet.data.Method.<init>(Method.java:361)
        at org.restlet.data.Method.<clinit>(Method.java:48)
        at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.<init>(ClientResource.java:396)



            May 10, 2015 10:04:32 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader loadClass
        INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load org.simpleframework.transport.connect.Connection.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
        java.lang.IllegalStateException
            at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1566)
            at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
            at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Unknown Source)
            at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelper(Engine.java:781)
            at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelpers(Engine.java:813)
            at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelpers(Engine.java:853)
            at org.restlet.engine.Engine.discoverConnectors(Engine.java:544)
            at org.restlet.engine.Engine.<init>(Engine.java:379)
            at org.restlet.engine.Engine.register(Engine.java:301)
            at org.restlet.engine.Engine.register(Engine.java:290)
            at org.restlet.engine.Engine.getInstance(Engine.java:199)
            at org.restlet.data.Method.<init>(Method.java:337)
            at org.restlet.data.Method.<init>(Method.java:396)
            at org.restlet.data.Method.<init>(Method.java:361)
            at org.restlet.data.Method.<clinit>(Method.java:48)
            at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.<init>(ClientResource.java:396)



        INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load java.net.InetSocketAddress.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
        java.lang.IllegalStateException
            at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1566)
            at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
            at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Unknown Source)
            at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelper(Engine.java:781)
            at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelpers(Engine.java:813)
            at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelpers(Engine.java:853)
            at org.restlet.engine.Engine.discoverConnectors(Engine.java:544)
            at org.restlet.engine.Engine.<init>(Engine.java:379)
            at org.restlet.engine.Engine.register(Engine.java:301)
            at org.restlet.engine.Engine.register(Engine.java:290)
            at org.restlet.engine.Engine.getInstance(Engine.java:199)
            at org.restlet.data.Method.<init>(Method.java:337)
            at org.restlet.data.Method.<init>(Method.java:396)
            at org.restlet.data.Method.<init>(Method.java:361)
            at org.restlet.data.Method.<clinit>(Method.java:48)
            at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.<init>(ClientResource.java:396)


        INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load org.restlet.data.Protocol.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
        java.lang.IllegalStateException
            at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1566)
            at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
            at org.restlet.ext.simple.HttpServerHelper.<init>(HttpServerHelper.java:57)
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
            at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelper(Engine.java:781)
            at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelpers(Engine.java:813)
            at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelpers(Engine.java:853)
            at org.restlet.engine.Engine.discoverConnectors(Engine.java:544)
            at org.restlet.engine.Engine.<init>(Engine.java:379)
            at org.restlet.engine.Engine.register(Engine.java:301)
            at org.restlet.engine.Engine.register(Engine.java:290)
            at org.restlet.engine.Engine.getInstance(Engine.java:199)
            at org.restlet.data.Method.<init>(Method.java:337)
            at org.restlet.data.Method.<init>(Method.java:396)
            at org.restlet.data.Method.<init>(Method.java:361)
            at org.restlet.data.Method.<clinit>(Method.java:48)
            at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.<init>(ClientResource.java:396)


        INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load java.util.logging.Logger.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
        java.lang.IllegalStateException
            at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1566)
            at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
            at org.restlet.engine.log.LoggerFacade.getLogger(LoggerFacade.java:117)
            at org.restlet.engine.Engine.getLogger(Engine.java:255)
            at org.restlet.Context.getCurrentLogger(Context.java:81)
            at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelper(Engine.java:785)
            at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelpers(Engine.java:813)
            at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelpers(Engine.java:853)
            at org.restlet.engine.Engine.discoverConnectors(Engine.java:544)
            at org.restlet.engine.Engine.<init>(Engine.java:379)
            at org.restlet.engine.Engine.register(Engine.java:301)
            at org.restlet.engine.Engine.register(Engine.java:290)
            at org.restlet.engine.Engine.getInstance(Engine.java:199)
            at org.restlet.data.Method.<init>(Method.java:337)
            at org.restlet.data.Method.<init>(Method.java:396)
            at org.restlet.data.Method.<init>(Method.java:361)
            at org.restlet.data.Method.<clinit>(Method.java:48)
            at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.<init>(ClientResource.java:396)
```

I checked and the simple.jar is part of the deployed war.

Can someone please suggest what this illegal access is and how I can solve it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you mixed the standalone and the embedded approach of Restlet:

- With the standalone approach, you need a server connector like Simple framework or Jetty and Restlet is responsible to manage them (start, stop)
- With the embedded approach, Restlet no longer need to manage this. You start your servlet engine and requests will be delegated to Restlet through its adapter servlet.

Do you make a try within Eclipse using the standalone approach or embedded one (with WTP for example)?

Here is a Maven file that allows you to create an embedded project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"           
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
        http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.restlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>restlet-war</artifactId>
    <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-snapshot</version>

    <properties>
        <java-version>1.7</java-version>
        <restlet-version>2.3.1</restlet-version>
        <wtp-version>2.0</wtp-version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.restlet</artifactId>
            <version>${restlet-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${restlet-version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven-restlet</id>
            <name>Public online Restlet repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.restlet.com</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java-version}</source>
                    <target>${java-version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>sources</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <wtpapplicationxml>true</wtpapplicationxml>
                    <wtpversion>${wtp-version}</wtpversion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Initializing the project for Eclipse can be done using the command `mvn eclipse:eclipse`.

You can find a complete simple project at this address: https://github.com/templth/restlet-stackoverflow/tree/master/restlet/test-restlet-servlet.

Hope it will help you,
Thierry

Comment: Hi Thierry, I am using Restlet for only ClientResource part to make calls to external servers and using representations like jackson to convert the response back to java objects.   I am still not sure what the issue is. I think what you are suggesting is for setting up a Rest based server using restlet.

Comment: Hi Karan. Okay, I see better the use case now. You shouldn't have the jar for the simple framework and corresponding Restlet extension in your classpath since it's used as a server connector (and you only to use client connectors)... Perhaps that's the reason of your problem! Hope it helps you

Comment: I am using the following four in my pom file...org.restlet (jse) , org.restlet.ext.simple, org.restlet.ext.servlet, org.restlet (gwt)  Which of these you suggest should be enough for my client side use only.

Comment: I would suggest not to use `org.restlet.ext.simple` and `org.restlet.ext.servlet` for client side and to use a client connector for HTTP like `org.restlet.ext.httpclient` if you're in Java (not GWT). As matter of fact the internal client connector of Restlet isn't very stable. For GWT nothing more needs to be added. Hope it's clear...